# mapping values are not allowed here - YAML

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I have prepared one YAML file for my main python code , Its getting an error while loading , Pls suggest for correction in YAML file .

mapping values are not allowed here - line 4, column 9

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "C:\Users\rajangra\PycharmProjects\jinja2/yaml_input/input.yaml", line 4, column 9

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried changing many parameters but still getting same error

```
---
region:
  - SGC
    ring:
    - Rosebank Ring 7
      hostname:
      - SGC_CrownLongmeM_SARA-1
            system_ip: 10.172.97.217
            ptp_ip:  10.172.101.217
            isis_id: 3
            port: 1/3/4
            interface:
              - SGC_ABR_12-1
                dest_ip: 10.172.97.1
              - SGC_ABR_12-2
                dest_ip: 10.172.97.2
      - SGC_SunningParkOLD_SAR8-1
            system_ip: 10.172.64.16
            ptp_ip:  10.172.68.16
            isis_id: 3
            port: 1/3/4
            interface:
              - SGC_ABR_12-1
                dest_ip: 10.172.64.1
              - SGC_ABR_12-2
                dest_ip: 10.172.64.2
```

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "C:\Users\rajangra\PycharmProjects\jinja2/yaml_input/input.yaml", line 4, column 9

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line, plain, scalars such as `SGC ring` and `Rosebank Ring 7 hostname` cannot be a keys for mapping, either quote them

```
region:
  - 'SGC
    ring':
    - 'Rosebank Ring 7
      hostname':
```

or put them on one line:

```
region:
  - SGC ring:
    - Rosebank Ring 7 hostname:
```

(another possibility is that you forgot to insert a dash before `ring` resp. `hostname`).